# How to change a style in CSS such that it affects only code in a `section` or a `div`

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to style the rendering of a piece of HTML code, which is automatically produced and then completed with a header. I can add style information in the header, but have limited influence on the HTML pieces which are produced and inserted. (Background: I am using Pandoc to render markdown text, where the HTML snippets produced are inserted in a template before writing into a file.).

The question is how to change a CSS rule for a part of HTML. I assumed (naively) that a class based selector, e.g. `img.content` would be applied in all elements included in a `div` with this classe:

In the style part of the head

```
...
img.content {max-height: 300px;}
...
```

and in the body

```
...
<img ... another image ... >
...
<div class=content> 
....
    <img ... myImage ... > 

</div>
```

where `myImage` would be shown with the max-height specified, but other images (e.g. `anotherImage` not affected.

This seems not to work, but I cannot add `class=content` to the place where the `img` tag is used.

Is there a way to achieve in HTML/CSS a rule which affects only selectors in certain parts of the code?

I add a running example of what I mean:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/templates/static/w3c.css" type="text/css">
  <style>
    img {
      max-height: 20px;
    }
    
    img.content {
      max-height: 40px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>My First Heading</h1>
  <img src="pic_trulli.jpg" alt="Italian Trulli">
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  <div class=content>
    <!-- code I cannot change but where pictures should be bigger  -->
    <img src="pic_trulli.jpg" alt="Italian Trulli">
    <!-- end -->
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `img.content` selects image elements that have the class `content`. Your code does not have this. Your code has a `div` with the class `content`. To select that image you could use `div.content > img` or `div.content img`. Read up on CSS selectors at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div had class `.content` not the img, so it's `.content img`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <style>
    img {
      max-height: 20px;
    }
    
    .content img {
      max-height: 40px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>My First Heading</h1>
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/hZj77BZ/lena01.jpg" alt="Lena">
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  <div class=content>
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/hZj77BZ/lena01.jpg" alt="Lena">
    <!-- end -->
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you - this should work for my complex code!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the child selector `>`. The `>` combinator selects nodes that are direct children of the first (parent) element. `img.content` will only work if you have specified a class called content for the image.

```css
div.content > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/templates/static/w3c.css" type="text/css">
  <style>
    img {
      max-height: 20px;
    }
    
    img.content {
      max-height: 40px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>My First Heading</h1>
  <img src="pic_trulli.jpg" alt="Italian Trulli">
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  <div class="content">
    <!-- code I cannot change but where pictures should be bigger  -->
    <img src="pic_trulli.jpg" alt="Italian Trulli">
    <!-- end -->
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This was helpful to guide my thinking. In my case, there may be more code between the div and the img which I cannot control. Thus this solution would not work (my error in posing the question!) but the other does. Thank you, nevertheless.

Comment: @user855443 `.content > img`  does the exact same thing as  `.content img`, it just targets images nested in the `content` div. Just two different ways to write it. But no problem. Happy to help.

Comment: I had the understanding that `content > img` works only if the first is immedialy preceeding and `content img` even if other divs etc are in between. Is this not correct? Thank you for clarification!

Comment: @user855443 no it selects all of them. See here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp You would have to use `.content > img:nth-child(1)` to only select the first.